# Chrome uses 100% cpu on youtube after update

Tags: google-chrome, cpu, youtube, cpu-usage

Chrome 40 is using 100% cpu when playing youtube videos full screen
My CPU is core i5 @ 2ghz with intel 4400 gfx card. it should be able to play them and I dont remember having this issue b4 Chrome 40.

Does anybody else have this problem.

Comment: Given the 4 upvotes maybe yes? I'm not having any problems with Chrome 40, but I'm using the DX11 renderer on an Nvidia card, so... I guess I'm atypical. If I noticed anything is that Chrome 40 seems have improved behavior with respect to RAM consumption.

Answer (score 1):

It may be an issue with YouTube rather than Chrome itself.  YouTube recently switched to using HTML5 videos by default:  http://techcrunch.com/2015/01/27/youtube-goes-html5-flash-is-now-deader/

I'd report playback errors using the instructions here: https://www.youtube.com/html5

Also, in case it's a problem with Chrome or any installed extensions, try downloading Chrome Canary (a beta version that can be installed alongside regular Chrome).

Comment: FYI: You can get Canary here: https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html